# Magento 1.9 onepage checkout and PayPal order review issue

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, paypal

Our normal checkout (onepage) flow is this:

```
1.) Cart
2.) Billing/shipping information
3.) Payment method
4.) Review
```

When moving from step 3 to step 4, `checkout/onepage/savePayment/` is called. If selected payment method is NOT PayPal, user is then shown the last step of checkout if is `review` (on the same page).

However, if selected payment method is PayPal, user is then redirected to `paypal/checkout/review` page which is not the same as the last step in Onepage checkout flow.

If `Skip order review page` is set to `Yes` then the last step is completely skipped.

Is there a proper way to solve this issue?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We are having a similar issue to this. When a customer selects PayPal for payments method, it redirects the customer to the shopping cart and abandons the transaction completely.

We believe that it is because PayPal disabled certain methods on the classic PayPal API on December 1st 2017 which is what Magento 1.9 uses.

We are looking at using Braintree (Developed by PayPal) and a new gateway to then use that for PayPal payments.